# How can I add new table in existing Firebase Auth on React Native Expo app

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have set up a Firebase Auth in my react native app. I managed to run the app and create new user using email and password.

I did try to add create new user by defining new var to add new user's name table, then store the new name table in firebase using by defining db = firebase.firestore();, then inject new user's name using db.collection("users"), but it's not working. I got this error "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

How can I add new table in Firebase Auth on my react native expo app?

Here is my signup.js and firebase.js files.

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button as RNButton } from 'react-native';

import { Button, InputField, ErrorMessage } from '../components';
import Firebase from '../config/firebase';

const auth = Firebase.auth();

export default function SignupScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
  const [rightIcon, setRightIcon] = useState('eye');
  const [signupError, setSignupError] = useState('');

  const handlePasswordVisibility = () => {
    if (rightIcon === 'eye') {
      setRightIcon('eye-off');
      setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
    } else if (rightIcon === 'eye-off') {
      setRightIcon('eye');
      setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
    }
  };

  const onHandleSignup = async () => {
    try {
      if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .set({
          email: currentUser.email,
          displayName: displayName,
        });
      }

    } catch (error) {
      setSignupError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style='dark-content' />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Create new account</Text>
      <InputField
        inputStyle={{
          fontSize: 14
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          marginBottom: 20
        }}
        leftIcon='account'
        placeholder='Nick name'
        autoCapitalize='none'
        textContentType='name'
        autoFocus={true}
        value={displayName}
        onChangeText={text => setDisplayName(text)}
      />
      <InputField
        inputStyle={{
          fontSize: 14
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          marginBottom: 20
        }}
        leftIcon='email'
        placeholder='Enter email'
        autoCapitalize='none'
        keyboardType='email-address'
        textContentType='emailAddress'
        autoFocus={true}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <InputField
        inputStyle={{
          fontSize: 14
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          marginBottom: 20
        }}
        leftIcon='lock'
        placeholder='Enter password'
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
        textContentType='password'
        rightIcon={rightIcon}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
        handlePasswordVisibility={handlePasswordVisibility}
      />
      {signupError ? <ErrorMessage error={signupError} visible={true} /> : null}
      <Button
        onPress={onHandleSignup}
        backgroundColor='#f57c00'
        title='Signup'
        tileColor='#fff'
        titleSize={20}
        containerStyle={{
          marginBottom: 24
        }}
      />
      <RNButton
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        title='Go to Login'
        color='#fff'
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e93b81',
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 12
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#fff',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 24
  }
});
```

```js
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId
};

let Firebase;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default Firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving this to cloud functions, creating a listener to user creation events.

```
export const onCreateUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customerData = {
    // ...more data here
    email: user.email,
    id: user.id
  }
})
```

You can find more useful documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events